# raspberry pi + rfm69 - connecting via SPI [PYTHON]

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio, spi

I'm starting with RPI and I have a problem which I don't really understand.
I have RFM69CW module connected to my RPI
Pins:
[RFM69 pin] - [RPI pin]
3v3 - 17,
MOSI - 19,
MISO - 21,
CLK - 23,
NSS - 24,
DIO0 - 31,

I got simple code to write value to register and then reading it:

```
import spidev
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

spi = ""
def gpio_spi_init():
    global spi

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN)

    spi = spidev.SpiDev()
    spi.open(0,0)
    spi.mode = 0b00
    spi.bits_per_word = 8
    spi.max_speed_hz = 50000
    print "Init Succes"

def write(reg, value):
    global spi
    data = [reg | 0x80, value]
    spi.xfer(data)

def read(reg):
   global spi
   data = [reg & 0x7F, 0]
   resp = spi.xfer(data)
   return resp[1]

gpio_spi_init()
write(0x01, 0x04) # Setting up RegOpMode on Standby Mode
print read(0x01)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

After read from any register I always get 0 as result. I don't get where I'm doing sth wrong.
I also try to use xfer2 and its the same problem.